# Java jjwt externalize signing of the token using HSM or vault

Tags: java, jwt, sign, hashicorp-vault, hsm

I have a jjwt for generating tokens in my Spring Boot app:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The token is created as

```
Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY * 1000))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret).compact();
```

I would like to however use HSM or vault for signing the token.
How the signing process of jjwt can be externalized?

Basically I would like to replace `.signWith` with implementation of signing on HSM or vault.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nimbus library for this purpose.

implementation "com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:10.4"

And you should add Provider

```
private JWSSigner getJWSSigner(PrivateKey privateKey) throws JOSEException {
        JWSSigner jwsSigner = new ECDSASigner(privateKey, Curve.P_384);

        jwsSigner.getJCAContext().setProvider(HSMProvider);
        return jwsSigner;
    }
```